# How to preview a list of images by sliding the mouse?

Tags: image, dynamic

I'm trying to dynamically scrub over a list of images like in iphoto. Unfortunately, when the mouse moves from one side to the other, it's skipping frames which is confusing:

[image]

When the mouse runs off the end it should stay on the first or last image, just like when previewing photo albums in iPhoto.

Here's my code:

```
images = ConformImages[
  ExampleData /@ ExampleData["TestImage"], {xdim = 300, 200}, "Pad", 
  Padding -> Gray];
imageCount = Length@images;
lastpos = pos = {0, 0};
Dynamic[
 pos = MousePosition["Graphics", None];
 If[pos =!= None, lastpos = pos];
 n = Round[Rescale[lastpos[[1]], {0, xdim}, {1, imageCount}], 1]; 
 Show[images[[n]], ImageSize -> 400]]
```

Comment: I think it's the unpredictable framerate of dynamic that's breaking it.

Comment: Is [`ListAnimate[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListAnimate.html) not suitable?

Comment: @blochwave No, the slider isn't what I'm going for :)

Comment: Sure, thanks, just checking!

Comment: If you move mouse slowly does it show everything? Because if so then in case of fast movement it is limited by your machine ability to render/transfer stuff fast.

Comment: So, can you answer me or it's not relevant anymore and we can close the topic?